# Controling duplicates in SQL database

Tags: c#, sql

I've created an application that is used for controlling and recording contactless cards. When the card is pressed against the reader, my application records the cards serial number (if the serial number is read, the card is functioning properly) and stores it into a local SQL database.

All this works fine, with one error that I can't solve. I marked the serial number column as Primary key so that if the same card is read, an exception would be thrown indicating that that specific card has already been recorded.

The weird thing that keeps happening is that this exception is thrown exactly 6 times (every time), and then it stops appearing and the duplicate cards get recorded as normal ones. What is causing this, and is there some other way to control the input and warn the user about duplicates.

I use C# in VS 2010 and SQL Server 2005 to create my application, how can I solve this?

Comment: Are you sure the value for the duplicate key is truly a duplicate?  No hidden spaces or a misidentified number?

Comment: Yes I'm sure, the serial number is assigned during the process of making the chip inside the card.

Comment: Is there any chance that you are using queues in this application?  The number "6" sticks in my mind as the number of retries that a queue uses for dirty entries.

Comment: I'm using simple INSERT INTO statements, no queues - every card is recorded instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you another aproach on that

It is not a really good idea to let the insert break to check duplicates.

just check the duplicate prior to insert with a select and that should solve the problem.

Comment: Wouldn't that slow the application significantly? We are talking about few thousand cards here

Comment: well if you got an clustered index on that field it should not really matter that much untill you get to few milions of records. And anyway the server needs to check that field too :)

Comment: Agreed. Checking if the data exists prior to entering it into the data would be a much better way of doing this.

Comment: So in the context of C# - you mean that I should just use the SQLCommand (with SELECT statement as Command text) and if the number of rows affected is larger than 0, to throw an exception?

Comment: as an alternative, use a standard autoincrement int primary key, and put your serial number in a separate indexed column with a UNIQUE constraint.

Comment: yes just make the select and check how manny row's you got back but if you got for instance a table with multiple fields make select like:
SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID = '0001' since that way it is much faster then SELECT * also be aware of the sql isolation level:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Based on Jesters suggestion what I recommend you do is to create a stored procedure that first checks if the data exists, if yes then returns a BIT 0 if no then inserts the data and returns BIT 1.

Then in your codebehind you can call this and check the result, A true value means data was inserted, a false value means it already existed.

This saves your application from throwing exceptions etc and generally makes the program structure more solid because you are not allowing the error to occur in the first place.

Checking if the data exists before trying to insert should not impact performance if your table is properly indexed.